# Passing procedure of object without referring to the procedure's type

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe7

I need to pass a `procedure of object` as parameter without using a procedure type as parameter.

I've tried using `Pointer` type as follows:

```
  TMyMethod = procedure () of object;
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
  public
    procedure CallMethod(AMethod : Pointer);
    procedure ShowCaption();
  end;


procedure TForm1.CallMethod(AMethod : Pointer);
begin
  TMyMethod(AMethod^)();
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  CallMethod(@ShowCaption);
end;

procedure TForm1.ShowCaption();
begin
  ShowMessage(Self.Caption);
end;
```

...but it produces an E2036 on compiling, at `CallMethod(@ShowCaption);` line:

```
[dcc32 Error] Unit1.pas(33): E2036 Variable required
```

Comment: `procedure ShowCaption()` is obviously not a variable. Why don't you grasp the error message and assign the procedure you want to hand over to a variable and then provide that variable? A variable of type `TMyMethod` would fit `ShowCaption()`. But if you insist on "without using a procedure type as parameter" then assign it to a naked `Pointer` type.

Comment: In your question you used a `Pointer` type as argument and in your answer you used a `TMethod`.  You claim you can't use a procedure type as an argument, but it's not clear what your restrictions are.  Why can't you use a procedure type and why is using a `TMethod` ok?  It's difficult to help when we don't understand why you're constrained to not use standard solutions or what those constraints are.

Comment: @J... My application uses runtime packages and is composed by several BPLs that doesn't have dependecies with the other BPLs but they must be able to pass things (methods in this case) to each other. The sender and the receiver both knows which should be the method definition, but they don't have a common type definition for the method interface (I could put the method definition in a common BPL but in that case it will be required to recompile all BPLs that requires the common BPL each time I add or change something in the common BPL)...

Comment: @J... ... So I thought to define in a common base class a procedure like `DoSomething(const AKey : string; AMethod : ???)`. Each child class should overrides the procedure and implements some interactions, i.e: `if(AKey = 'ShowCaption') then  FReceivedShowCaptionMethod := AMethod;`.

Comment: @Fabrizio You can define the `TMyMethod` type in each BPL, and it will be assignment-compatible across BPL boundaries.  You don't need a common BPL to define it. Just define the parameter type as `procedure of object`, it will work just fine

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution by using the `TMethod` type:

```
  TMyMethod = procedure () of object;
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
  public
    procedure CallMethod(AMethod : TMethod);
    procedure ShowCaption();
  end;

procedure TForm1.CallMethod(AMethod : TMethod);
begin
  TMyMethod(AMethod)();
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  Meth : TMethod;
begin
  Meth.Data := Self;
  Meth.Code := @TForm1.ShowCaption;

  CallMethod(Meth);
end;

procedure TForm1.ShowCaption();
begin
  ShowMessage(Self.Caption);
end;
```

It seems to work good, but I'm wondering if it's safe or if it can drive to other problems.

If there's a better/alternative way, please post it and I'll be glad to consider it

Comment: You said: "The sender and the receiver both knows which should be the method definition, but they don't have a common type definition for the method interface [...]".  Problem is, the sender and reciever still must agree upon (have a common knowledge of) the type of the object (Meth.Data). You might run into trouble when you change the object's class (TForm1) and recompile just one side. Perhaps just use a simple procedure? (Not procedure of object.)

Comment: "*I'm wondering if it's safe*" - no, becaue the caller could pass in a `TMethod` that refers to ANY class method that is not compatible with the signature that `TMyMethod` requires. "*If there's a better/alternative way*" - yes, just use `procedure of object` normally, it will work just fine, even across BPL boundaries

Comment: FYI, there is an easier/safer way for the caller to use `TMethod` *correctly* - DON'T declare `Meth` as `TMethod` byt as `TMyMethod`, and then type-cast it when passing it in: `procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject); var Meth : TMyMethod; begin Meth := Self.ShowCaption; CallMethod(TMethod(Meth)); end;` Rely on type-safety as much as possible.